# NoClassDefFoundError for dependent library projects in Android app project (using maven as build tool)

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I developed two Android library projects: **Project A (MyBaseA)** & **Project B(MyBaseB)**.

I am using maven as build tool, **MyBaseA** is a `<dependency>` of **MyBaseB**.

I also have an Android app project which uses the built **MyBaseB.jar** as library, this jar is added to the build path of the Android app project.

For **library project A**, the maven coordinate definition in pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.base.a</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBaseA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyBaseA</name>
    ...
```

For **library project B** which is dependent on above **library project A** project, the **pom.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.base.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBaseB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <name>MyBaseB</name>

    <dependencies>
      <!--include library project A as dependency-->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.base.a</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyBaseA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
      ...
   </dependencies>
```

I `mvn clean install` library project **A** & **B** which are all successful.

Under `target/` directory of **project B**, there are **MyBaseB.ap_**, **MyBaseB.apklib** & **MyBaseB.jar** files.

At this point, I created a new Android app project, in which I included the above **MyBaseB.jar** to the build path of my new Android app project, and used java classes defined in **MyBaseB** project, which in turns call functions defined in **MyBaseA** project.

But when I run my new Android app project, I got exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.base.a.ProjectAClass` .

My android app can not find the java class defined in **project A**. Then I checked the content of **MyBaseB.jar**, all classes of **library project A** are **not** included in **MyBaseB.jar**.  Why? I think the **MyBaseB.jar** should include **project A** classes, because the pom has included **project A** as a `<dependency>`. Why this error happen?

**==================== Update =====================**

After I changed **library project A** 's `<packaging>` section of pom from **jar** to **apklib** , and added the `<type>apklib</type>` in the dependency of **project B (MyBaseB)**:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.base.a</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyBaseA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
   </dependency>
```

now the **MyBaseB.jar**  contains classes of **project A**. The above problem solved ( I checked the content of **MyBaseB.jar**, now, it contains all classes of **project A**, previously, it didn't.

But the new problem is that, when I run my Android app, the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` occurs whenever a class of **project A** is instantiated. That's when app reaches :

```
ProjectAClass projAclass = new ProjectAClass();
```

I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Why? Why it complains even now the **MyBaseB.jar** contains the ProjectAClass.class.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the dependency is only used to *compile* your library. Maven will not do anything more in this case and will presume that the library will be deployed along with the required dependencies.

What you want is either:

- Deploy the **MyBaseA** library to a location available to your library classpath (probably not possible since you are deploying on android, but I haven't really explored the matter enough to be conclusive), or
- Shade the dependencies inside your library.

Shading is done using the **maven-shade-plugin**, by adding it the pom of your **MyBaseB** project:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <!-- Exclude cryptographic signatures from dependencies, 
                       almost always mandatory (can cause security errors otherwise) -->
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The plugin will add all dependencies on the **compile** scope (the default), along with your project, inside a final über-jar.

More detail and examples are available on [the maven-shade-plugin website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but I don't think this is the way I should go, please check my update (after changing the <packaing> of project A from jar to apklib, the project B jar contains all classes of project A already.)